# Propagate Indexes when CREATE TABLE from two tables in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing

I create a table by linking two different tables in PostgreSQL. I do this with a sentence like this:

```
CREATE TABLE t_aux_prop_delay
AS
SELECT r.cell, r.kpi_name, r.the_geom, d.max as pd_end_point, round(k.avg_samples, 2) AS avg_samples
from t_cell_regions r, kpi_definition d,
    (
    SELECT cell, kpi_name, avg(kpi_value) AS avg_samples
    from t_prop_delay_values
    GROUP BY cell, kpi_name
    ) k
WHERE r.kpi_name = d.kpi_name
AND r.cell = k.cell
AND r.kpi_name = k.kpi_name
ORDER BY r.cell, d.max;
```

I want to know if it is possible to **propagate the indexes** from one of those tables to the new table so I do not have to create them all over again.

Comment: No, not possible. You need to create the needed indexes manually

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm afraid so...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this select can help you:

```
SELECT REPLACE(indexdef, indexname, indexname||1) 
FROM pg_indexes 
WHERE TABLENAME = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME';
```

It will give you a "CREATE INDEX" code with a different name (that is why I have added/concatenated 1 at the end). You are creating a new object so it has to have a different name...

And here is another code where you can also get the "CREATE INDEX" code with the different table name.

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(indexdef, indexname, indexname||1), tablename, 'your_tablename') 
FROM pg_indexes 
WHERE TABLENAME = 'personeel_medspec';
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do not really understand the purpose of getting that code. Could you please explain me a bit more in deep how is this linked to my problem or what it will lead to? Thanks!

Comment: I have understood that you want to create new indexes on a new table but they already exist on an old table ?

Comment: mmm not quite. What I want is for those indexes existing on a table to be created automatically when creating the new table, which comes from linking two other tables. Maybe I am missunderstanding what you are saying.. if that is the case I'm sorry!